# Wake on Lan Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, ethernet

Настроил *wake on lan* на пк, но после выключения и простоя примерно в 3 часа, он не  реагирует на включение по пакету... Из чего сделал вывод, сетевой контроллер спустя опредмеченное время прекращает работать.
Как увеличить время работы?
Чипсет: Z97

Comment: От розетки компьютер при этом точно не выключается?

Comment: Нет, а что такого не должно быть?

Comment: На всех тех компьютерах, на которых я настраивал WoL и которые не отключались от розетки ни на секунду, этот самый WoL продолжал успешно работать и через несколько дней после выключения. Так что на первый взгляд похоже на чипсето/материнкоспецифичные проблемы

Comment: **1.** Предлагаю проверить и изменить настройки BIOS, имеющие отношение к данному вопросу: **Power On By PCI-E/PCI**; **ERP Ready**; **Resume by onboard LAN**  и пр. **2.** Если не поможет - поискать информацию на профильных форумах по данной системной плате, может даже прошить нужный firwmware. **3.** Наконец, обратиться в техподдержку производителя системной платы

Comment: @Daemon-5 , спасибо за помощь, обязательно попробую и отпишусь)